# FOR XML could not serialize the data for node because it contains a character (0x0001) which is not allowed in XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use FOR XML for the first time in T-SQL on SQL Server 2008. I am getting this error message for one of the columns in my big table:

```
FOR XML could not serialize the data for node because it contains a character (0x0001) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.
```

I took a guess and tried this:

```
select * from db.dbo.table where colThatGeneratedError like '%0x0001%'
```

but it pulls no rows.

How can I find out what row in the table contains the invalid characters?

What character does 0x0001 refer to? To my eye that looks like hex for 1 = decimal 1

Comment: Try`'%\u0001%'`. Not sure. You could try `\u0030`, digit '0,' first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TSQL you can use CHAR function, e.g.

```
select * from db.dbo.table where CHARINDEX(CHAR(1), colThatGeneratedError) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
FROM (SELECT a = '<'+nchar(2)+'>') x
for xml path(''),type
```

you will get this error for above statemnet.

> FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'a' because it contains
>   a character (0x0002) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this
>   data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type
>   and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

I have created a sql function to fix this problem

```
USE master;
GO
IF (OBJECT_ID('str_to_xml') IS NOT NULL) DROP FUNCTION dbo.str_to_xml;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.str_to_xml(@input AS nvarchar(max))
RETURNS xml
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int, @iText nvarchar(100);
    SET @i = 0x0;
    WHILE (@i <= 0x8)
    WHILE (@i <= 0xFFFF)
    BEGIN
        SET @iText = master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(@i);
        SET @iText = ISNULL(STUFF(@iText, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0x]%', @iText) - 1, ''), '0');
        SET @iText = '&#x' + CASE WHEN LEN(@iText) > 1 THEN '' ELSE '0' END + @iText + ';';
        SET @input = REPLACE(@input, @iText, '');
        SET @i = CASE
            WHEN @i + 1 BETWEEN 0x9 AND 0xA THEN 0xA
            WHEN @i + 1 = 0xD THEN 0xD
            WHEN @i + 1 BETWEEN 0x20 AND 0xD7FF THEN 0xD7FF
            WHEN @i + 1 BETWEEN 0xE000 AND 0xFFFD THEN 0xFFFD
            ELSE @i + 1 END + 1;
    END
    RETURN CONVERT(xml, @input);
END
GO
```

usage:

```
select master.dbo.str_to_xml((select *
FROM (SELECT a = '<'+nchar(2)+'>') x
for xml path('')))
```

Comment: Wow. It works, but it's not efficient. You do a replace for each character in those ranges - and there's like 2000 different characters. Also, I noticed a mistake. You increment by 2 most of the time instead of 1. It should be:

ELSE @i END + 1;

What you should do is convert the string to a character array, and then check each character for being in a "bad range". You can probably do this without using while loops too. 

But even better, remove "TYPE" after "FOR XML" and there's no error. I guess because the result is a string and not an XML data type.

Comment: Also, you have 2 while statements. I think the "WHILE (@i <= 0x8)" is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select * from db.dbo.table where (PATINDEX('%[A,Z,0-9]%[A,Z,0-9]%[A,Z,0-9]%',colThatGeneratedError) >0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select left(youValuCol, ' ')
from yourTable
for xml path ('test')
```

It works for me. propably it is a special enter from excel.